# How to add total decimal values in alert for a switch

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, alert, prompt

How do you add the total character values being "decimal" that are entered in the prompt to be alerted. Many thanks.

```js
var sw = prompt("Enter scrable word in caps:")

switch (sw){
  
  case "A": decimal=1;break;
  case "B": decimal=3;break;
  case "C": decimal=3;break;
  case "D": decimal=2;break;
  case "E": decimal=1;break;
  case "F": decimal=4;break;
  case "G": decimal=2;break;
  case "H": decimal=4;break;
  case "I": decimal=1;break;
  case "J": decimal=8;break;
  case "K": decimal=5;break;
  case "L": decimal=1;break;
  case "M": decimal=3;break;
  case "N": decimal=1;break;
  case "O": decimal=1;break;
  case "P": decimal=3;break;
  case "Q": decimal=10;break;
  case "R": decimal=1;break;
  case "S": decimal=1;break;
  case "T": decimal=1;break;
  case "U": decimal=1;break;
  case "V": decimal=4;break;
  case "W": decimal=4;break;
  case "X": decimal=8;break;
  case "Y": decimal=4;break;
  case "Z": decimal=10;break;
 
  default: decimal="Not a capital letter";
}

alert("The score for"+sw+"is:"+decimal)
```

Comment: didn't get you question. What do you mean by " total character values being "decimal""

Comment: I want to know how to find the total and alert it - for example if MAN is entered into the prompt the value given to M is 3, A is 1 and N is 1, so the total would be 5. Therefore I want to know how to output 5 in this case, getting the total value of MAN. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should probably just have an object with each letters score, and then `.split` the input and use `.reduce` to get the score:

```
var values =  { A: 1, B: 3, C: 3, D: 2, E: 1, F: 4, G: 2, H: 4, I: 1,J: 8, K: 5, L: 1, M: 3, N: 1, O: 1, P: 3, Q: 10, R: 1, S: 1, T: 1, U: 1, V: 4, W: 4, X: 8,  Y: 4, Z: 10 }

var sw = prompt("Enter scrable word in caps:")
var letters = sw.split('');
var score = letters.reduce(function(accumulator, current) {
    return accumulator + values[current];  
}, 0);
alert(score);
```